# Select all parents with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, select, jquery-selectors

How can I select all parent elements that have one specific class?
For example:

```
<ul class="123">
  <li>
  <li>
    <ul class="qwe">
      <li>
      <li>
        <ul class="123">
          <li class="select">
          <li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

How can I select all parent ul elements according to the li with class 'select' that have class '123'?

Comment: Just as a side note. You know that HTML markup is invalid right? (Not closing the `li` tags.

Comment: @putvande I thought that was only for some strict modes in 4.x? I could be wrong though - I don't know what HTML5 requires as far as 4's "optional" closing tags (</tr></td></li>, maybe a couple others)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('.select').parents('.123');
```

Or maybe the more specific:

```
$('li.select').parents('ul.123');
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but `.parent()` or `.closest("ul")` might make more sense, so it doesn't traverse the whole way up the DOM and/or possibly return more parents than needed

Comment: @Ian, I'm also not sure what the OP wants, but the question says "all parents"...

Comment: @bfavaretto That's why I commented; I didn't realize what the actual HTML structure was (I thought it was flat), so the unclosed `<li>` elements threw me off :)

Answer (score 2):

How about an alternative using the `has()` method:

```
$("ul.123").has("li.select")
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/6wB49/

---

**[has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)**

> **Description**: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a
>   descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

Comment: I think this has the potential to do less work, while achieving what's needed (instead of using `.parents()`)

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-class-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('ul[class="123"] li.select');

//Or

$('li.select').parents('ul.123');
```

Comment: +1 for the link back to jQuery's Class Selectors page. Oh, but that (now) first example doesn't return the ul does it?

Comment: Ah, yes. Now it's Updated

Comment: Please dare to comment DOWNVOTERS. Please explain.

Comment: I'll guess its b/c of the first method you had or because the `[class="123"]` isn't as elegant as `.123`

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

You can also try this....

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul').bind('click', function () {
                $(this).parent().each(function () {
                    alert($(this).attr('title'));
                });
            });
            $('li').bind('onclick', function () {
                $(this).parent().each(function () {
                    alert($(this).html());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div title="div">
        <ul class="123" title="1111_1">
            <li title="test_1">Test 1</li>
            <li title="test_2">Test 2</li>
            <ul class="qwe" title="qwe">
                <li title="qwe_1">ABC 1</li>
                <li title="qwe_2">ABC 2</li>
                <ul class="123" title="123">
                    <li class="select" title="123_1">XYZ 1</li>
                    <li title="123_2">XYZ 2</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**